# Nginx: Forward HTTPS traffic to a proxy server requiring authentication

Tags: nginx, proxy, https

I need to set up a transparent HTTP/HTTPS server (proxy X) with NGINX to proxy the traffic with the authorization needed to the proxy endpoint (proxy Y). The proxy endpoint (B) requires basic authorization to accept traffic.

**The analogy would be like this:**

Client `C` requests URL (e.g. ifconfig.co) **->** Custom DNS resolves the request to proxy `X` **->** Proxy `(X)` accepts request and manipulate header to add basic authentication **->** Proxy `X` forwards request to proxy endpoint `Y`

It should achieve the exact result as the below cURL:
Here I use https://ifconfig.co to check the endpoint IP.

### HTTP

```
curl -x http://proxy_endpoint:proxy_port -U 'username':'password' -k https://ifconfig.co
```

### HTTPS

```
curl -x http://proxy_endpoint:proxy_port -U 'username':'password' -k https://ifconfig.co
```

---

### Testing:

To test the setup, I add a record in my `/etc/hosts` to resolve `ifconfig.co` to my Proxy X server

Then, I do a cURL

```
#http
curl http://ifconfig.co

#https
curl https://ifconfig.co
```

A successful result should give me the IP of the endpoint proxy `Y`

---

### HTTP traffic:

I have extensively searched online for a solution using NGINX modules and I have found a very helpful answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/345244/954119

However, this answer only helped me send HTTP traffic, not HTTPS. Here is what I configured for HTTP on port 80 in nginx.conf:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  300;

    proxy_set_header  Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  server {
    listen *:80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://proxy_endpoint_Y:PORT;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization "Basic base64-encoded-string";
    }
  }


}
```

So I set the `http` directive with `server` that listens on port 80 and configured `location` with `proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization` with bas64 encoded username/pass.

This works very well actually and does proxy HTTP(port 80) traffic to the proxy endpoint, however, HTTPS traffic won't work.

---

### HTTPS traffic

So, when I changed `listen` to `443` instead:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  300;

  server {
    listen *:443;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://proxy_endpoint_Y:PORT;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization "Basic base64-encoded-string";
    }
  }


}
```

cURL error on my Client `C`:

```
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

In my access logs, I get a very weird log:

```
xx.xxx.xx.x - - [26/Mar/2022:21:43:54 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xE1\x01\x00\x00\xDD\x03\x03W\x87>\x1E+1\xDFb\x13\x1E,\xC0\xE9\xEF\x07\xAB[\xEA!\xBE\x17\xC23\x8D\xBD\xA4\xEA\xB5\xD5s\x8AO\x00\x00\x5C\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-"
```

---

I just need to manipulate HTTPS traffic to add authorization header? Is that possible? Or is there another way of approach?

### Note:

I've tried using `stream` module which I used before to send HTTPS traffic to endpoints, but with no authorization, but I don't see any option in NGINX `stream` module documentation to manipulate request headers. http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_module.html

### System Environment:

> nginx version: nginx/1.21.6 built by gcc 9.3.0 (Ubuntu
> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 TLS SNI support enabled

Comment: does not work is not an error description. please provide the full configuration of the 'does not work'  remind, that default port does not need to be declared

Comment: @djdomi Added more details and clarification to the post. Thanks.

Comment: For nginx to handle HTTPS [you need `listen *:443 ssl` plus directive(s) to set the certificate/chain and key](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html). With the config you have, nginx is expecting HTTP-clear on 443, so when the client actually uses HTTPS, the first SSL/TLS record (handshake ClientHello) comes out in your log as a garbage HTTP request `\x16\x03\x01etcetc`

Comment: PS: stream can neither parse/recognize nor modify HTTP headers because it does not require or expect HTTP, only bytes, and bytes have no headers or even lines.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for the clarification. I'm exploring other modules with NGINX such as https://github.com/chobits/ngx_http_proxy_connect_module#example-for-curl
It mentions basic authentication in the documentation and in the discussion as well. I will update the post once I have a clear view or found a solution.